# How can I make the entire button clickable? Even the elements inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I have read somewhere that I can use something called even bubbling, and stopPropagation(); to achieve this. Im a noob at Javascript so I have no idea how to implement, but this is what I have so far. I can click on the padding around the elements inside the button, but if I click on the elements, they do not trigger the button event. Any ideas?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.sidebar-button-switcher')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.show {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-switcher-container">
  <button class="sidebar-button-switcher" onclick="myFunction()">
            <img class="sidebar-icon" src="" height="20" width="20">
            <h3>Switch Views</h3>
            <img class="sidebar-icon" src="" height="20" width="20">
        </button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="btn-active">Asker</a>
    <a class="btn-active">Tasker</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `openDropdown.classList` should be `dropdowns[i].classList`.

Comment: Didn't you get an error in the JavaScript console because of that?

Comment: no, no errors. the button works perfectly, im trying to make the icons within the button also clickable, when I click the icons nothing happens. but when I inspect the elements, the "dropdown-content" turns purple, meaning its registering my click, just nothing happens

Comment: When I run the code above, I get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null** when I click on Switch Views.

Comment: Where is the `filterSelection()` function?

Comment: Why are you using both `myFunction` and `window.onclick` to handle clicks on the switcher button?

Comment: `<a>` is a link, it will reload the page after running `filterFunction()`.

Comment: Add `href="#"` to prevent that.

Comment: the filterSelection only applies to the dropdown menu. just trying to do the buttons icons for now. I cant figure out why youre getting an error. I dont get one

Comment: Could you please fix the code snippet so it doesn't get an error? You must have copied it wrong if you're not getting an error.

Comment: ok i fixed it, see if it works

Comment: `event.target.closest('.sidebar-button-switcher')`

Comment: When I run your snippet, the same thing happens when I click on the button and when I click on the icons inside it. I added `console.log()` to both handlers, and they both ran.

Comment: i am not sure what is wrong. When I run the code snippet and inspect and inspect the element, the button works properly. I can see the "show" appear and disappear. The same issue still persists when I try to click on the icons

Comment: @epascarello event.target.closest('.sidebar-button-switcher') works! Thank you! Please add it to the answer and i'll mark it as accepted